# Activating Audio for background image (Movie Clip) possible?

Tags: camera

I can't believe I couldn't find any thread anywhere about this but here's my problem.

I want to use a video with sound as background and animate a model according to the acoustic Cues given in the video (for timing). But for the life of me I can't find any way to hear the sound track of the video when playing back the timeline. what am i missing? Please don't tell me that this isn't possible that would be just ridiculous...

Regards. Oz

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, go to the sequencer, add the same video in there as well. Now you have audio while playing back. Remove the video track in the sequencer, keep the audio track, that way you can render your animation while working and see it, otherwise it will be overlayed by the video track.

Hope it helps anybody else.